# Query to return all values from next month

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, dateadd, getdate

I have a dataset of subscriptions in a table that looks something like this:

Table:
UserID
Subscription_type
Subscription_end_date

I'm trying to build a report in SSRS that shows a list of all subscriptions that are going to expire somewhere in the next month. The report gets sent on the first of every month and needs to show all the rows that are going to expire in the next month.

For example: a report sent on 01-07-2021 needs to show all subscriptions that are going to expire during August (so all subscription_end_date with a value from 01-08-2021 to 31-08-2021).

At first I thought using a where statement like the below one would be the answer:

```
WHERE [Subscription_end_date] = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE())
```

But somehow it doesn't return any values. I would like to know if my solution is in the right direction and that DATEADD combined with the GETDATE should do the trick or that I have to search it in a whole other statement.

Comment: Your `where` criteria is looking only for a *specific* date, so that would be 1 month on from the date you run it, ie, 01/08, you need to compare a *range*

Comment: `Getdate` returns `Datetime` value and `DATEADD` returned type is that type too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql So the query compares  `[Subscription_end_date]` to date + time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just check your target date is within the desired range,
try

```
where Subscription_end_date >= dateadd(month,1,convert(date,getdate())) 
  and Subscription_end_date <  dateadd(month,2,convert(date,getdate()))
```

Assuming of course you are running your report on the 1st of each month.

Comment: Thanks! Yes the report runs on the first of every month so should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The first date of the next month can be found using:

```
dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate()))
```

So, you can use this in a `where` clause:

```
where Subscription_end_date >= dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate())) and
      dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate())) < dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(getdate())))
```

Comment: @T.A.  Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Great to see the various ways in which in can be solved.

Comment: @T.A. . . . I believe this is the correct answer to the question you asked, which appears to be about a *calendar* month.  The other answer is different.  You can accept whatever answer you like, but you already accepted this so it seems to do what you want.

Comment: I would agree it's odd to change if the answer accomplishes the requirements